# Download link to /var/[myProject]/www/[myFolder]/[myFile]

Tags: html

How to create a download link to `/var/[myProject]/www/[myFolder]/[myFile]` using < a > tag? Click it and download it.

Use this

```
$zipPath = "/var/[projectName]/www/html/zip_download/Input.csv.zip";
...
<a href="<?php echo $bag->get("zipPath", ""); ?>"><?php echo $bag->get("zipFileName", ""); ?></a>
```

When click it, it unexpectedly goes to:
http://[hostName]/var/[projectName]/www/html/zip_download/Input.csv.zip

Comment: What's wrong with `<a href="/var/[myProject]/www/[myFolder]/[myFile]">`?

Comment: @DavidRobinson presumably that is a file on the server, which the client does not have access to directly.

Comment: @Ah- I thought it was a URL. In that case, this depends entirely on the server, framework and setup.

Comment: try setting `$zipPath` to `/zip_download/Input.csv.zip`.

Comment: With most server setups you can only access files in the `html` folder, for security reasons. Could you please elaborate, where the host file location is in relation to the desired download file?

Comment: I just want to hide the information which are the CSV files because it's related to banking. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are adding:

```
/var/[projectName]/www/
```

Just remove that it will run correctly. As adding /var/[projectName]/www/ means the folder is from

```
http://[hostName]/var/[projectName]/www/html/zip_download/Input.csv.zip
```

as WWW is website root and thus removing will get the properly working

```
http://[hostName]/html/zip_download/Input.csv.zip
```

Comment: I know what you mean but I want to store files in /var/.../www, not /var/www/. Hiding information.

Comment: Why you want to hide the file as if you are providing link to the user

Comment: The other purpose is to separate the website source code (/var/www) and the storage (/var/project/www).

Comment: then you should use something like this: http://hostname/../../../var/[projectName]/www/.... As .. will work as cd.. for linking

Comment: As generally directory before wwww is not accessible through http